# Set value of specific cell in pandas dataframe to sum of two other cells

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'X': [1.5, 6.777, 2.444, np.NaN],
          'Y': [1.111, np.NaN, 8.77, np.NaN],
          'Z': [5.0, 2.333, 10, 6.6666]})
```

I think this should work, but i get the following error;

```
df.at[1,'Z'] =(df.loc[[2],'X'] +df.loc[[0],'Y'])
```

How can I achieve this?

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Hi George, I edited your question. Please keep in mind that `pd.np` is deprecated. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve]. In particular you should add your expected output.

Comment: Don't put the row indices in brackets. and I don't think you need the outer parentheses

Comment: @rpanai First question, thanks for edit.

Comment: @JordanKohn That actually worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```py
df.loc[1, 'Z'] = df.loc[2,'X'] + df.loc[0,'Y']
```